# Laravel api rest + vue give me the error 405 method not allowed

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, rest, http-status-code-405

I have a laravel api rest + vue js application using vite and locally with xampp it works correctly but when I mount it in docker all post, put, etc. requests give me the error 405 method not allowed, it only supports get and head, I leave attached the dockerfile, the .env, the web.php and the api.php.

According to what I have tried, I think the error is in the dockerfile since locally with xampp it works fine.

```
--- Dockerfile ---

FROM php:8.1.0-apache-buster

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
zlib1g-dev \
libicu-dev \
libxml2-dev \
libpq-dev \
libzip-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql pgsql

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh| bash -- \
&& apt-get install -y nodejs \
&& apt-get autoremove -y

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

RUN apt update && apt install -y git
WORKDIR /var/www/html
\#Variable Para Repositorio GIT
ENV GIT_LINK=myprojectgitlink
ENV GIT_REP=master
\#Clonación del repositorio GIT
RUN git clone -b ${GIT_REP} ${GIT_LINK} .
\#Cambio de Permisos
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

\#Variable de ruta de documento index
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN sed -ri -e 's!DB_HOST=127.0.0.1!DB_HOST=db!g' /var/www/html/.env
RUN sed -ri -e 's!DB_PASSWORD=!DB_PASSWORD=pass111!g' /var/www/html/.env

RUN apt-get install -y npm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN node -v

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build
```

```
--- Env ---

APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY= MYKEY
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=112233

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

```
--- web.php ---

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('app');
});

Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

```
--- api.php ---

<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\HabitController;

Route::post('registerApi', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('loginApi', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function(){

    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);

    Route::get('user', [AuthController::class, 'userData']);

    Route::get('loadHabits', [HabitController::class, 'load']);
    Route::post('saveHabit', [HabitController::class, 'save']);
    Route::post('completeHabit/{id}', [HabitController::class, 'complete']);
    Route::post('deleteHabit/{id}', [HabitController::class, 'delete']);
});
```

Comment: you dont have any "put" route declared. Which route is throwing that error and which method ?

Comment: This can happen if your container is behind a proxy (e.g. a load balancer) and you also have an http to https redirect set up inside your container. Typically all https connections would terminate at the load balancer and then the internal traffic will be http so you will end up with a redirect from http to https in the container which will change all http request types to GET. In general be mindful of the fact that the default redirect types will change the HTTP verb to GET